# Adding Items To A ListView Through A WinForm?

Tags: winforms, listview

If I have a ListView embedded in a WinForm, is there any way I can simply click in the ListView and start typing in new items when the form is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At runtime, no.  The only edit option it has is the LabelEdit property.  Set it to true to allow the user to edit the ListViewItem.Text property of *existing* items.

Comment: Is it possible while running the form to select items in the ListView and delete them?

Comment: Sure, just implement the KeyDown event handler and delete the selected item if you see Keys.Delete.  Might want to implement a ContextMenuStrip as well so it will work with a mouse.  Being able to customize the list view in your code that way is the Power of Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio when you click on the listview a small triangle in the top right appears. When you click on it you can edit columns, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I meant while my program is running (I made an edit to my OP)